# Where can I buy IR filter glass?

Tags: diy, infrared-conversion

I want to do an IR conversion to my old Nikon D70 (swap the on-sensor filter), Where can I get raw IR filter glass from? Preferably in the UK. 
I am very capable with optics/electronics etc, but no clue where to get the actual filter material from.

I do NOT want recommendations for places that do the conversion for you.

Comment: I don't know f this will work for IR conversion, but I bought this a flash-controller filter [from Edmund Optics](http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/longpass-edge-filters/optical-cast-infrared-ir-longpass-filters/1918). (Maybe [this one](http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/longpass-edge-filters/infrared-ir-longpass-filters/3326)?)

Comment: Have you considered looking for 87/a/b/c, 88/a or 89b screw-on filters? Almost any thread size can be cut to cover a DX sensor (it's under 30mm diagonal, including the non-imaging edge pixels, so allowing for the under-mount area, you're not eliminating any popular filter sizes), and there ought to be more than a couple of them left over from the film days in the shops or on the used market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I buy my filter glass from these stores:

http://www.thorlabs.de/search/thorsearch.cfm?search=longpass

http://www.edmundoptics.com

If you buy the unmounted glass, you can cut it and mount it any way you want. Like in place of the IR cut filter.

Comment: Good call - not in the UK but could ship - although internationally shipping thin, expensive glass is a VERY bad plan!

Comment: No, I bought it internationally for my work many a time, and it is very well packed, I never had trouble.

Answer (score 2):

[MaxMax](http://www.maxmax.com) sells a wide range of filtering products for cameras. I'm a customer of theirs who had hope to use their front mounted filter to use my IR modified camera (modified for astrophotography, not IR work) for traditional street use.

I found their product not satisfactory. The initial filter had extremely poor quality control, you could see visible differences in the amount of filter material. The replacement (which arrived quickly and without complaint) was a different color than the original one. I was never sure which was the correct filter, the original or the replacement.

Autofocus did work with the Canon 40D, but it also worked without the Maxmax filter. Images looked fine with a custom white balance, but they also looked fine without the Maxmax filter.

I asked for a refund and was refused. To their credit the website clearly stated that refunds were not available.

So, they have a wide range of filter glass available, but triple check that what they have suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The [LifePixel](http://www.lifepixel.com/products) site sells the filters for Nikon and you can even choose what kind of filter you want: IR only, UV only or full spectrum (from UV to IR).

They provide the replacement service as well (ok, you do not want it, but it is not mandatory) and [tutorials](http://www.lifepixel.com/tutorials/infrared-diy-tutorials) about how to change the filter by yourself.

The big advantage is that the filters are already the right size and you do not have to cut anything, the quality should be the best compared with homemade cutted filters.

Note that after the conversion you have to recalibrate the Autofocus.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out Angstrom Precision Optics. Our website is www.apoptics.com. We currently have over 125 different types of filter glass material in house. The advantage of buying the material from APO is that we have the capabilities to fabricate just about size and shape parts that you may need. We are located in the US.

Thank you,
John J. OHerron
General Manager